# dataLayer.push() doesn't work the first time

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager

I've got a React app using GTM...

I've got an `dataLayer.push({'event': 'linkClicked'});`

The first time I click the link, no event is emitted.  Any other clicks, and the event is emitted.

I've confirmed via the chorme JS debugger and GA Debugger that

- the push code is getting hit every time
- the event gets emitted every time but the first time.

I can see the first and any subsequent events appear in the dataLayer.  But the GA Debugger only shows the the subsequent events...as does the real time Analytics..

Alternatively...I suppose the event push could be one behind, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Anybody seen this before?